# Howto use SASS parent selector for keeping declaration atomic in a structure with imports

Tags: css, sass

As mentioned [here](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector) it's possible to set properties based on e.g a class on a parent element.
I've tried it a while without luck to specify the color of a paragraph based on the sections background containing the paragraph to have all style definitions in the file for that paragraph to keep it atomic.

If I looked into the compiled `CSS` and saw something happens. I guess my filestructure broke things here because I created a lot of files and included them on the levels where these were needed.
Here's what I did:

```
// Main.scss
html{
 body{    
   #wrapper{
     @import "areas/section";
   }
 }
}

// _section.scss
section{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;

  &.black{
    background-color:#000;
  }

  &.white{
     background-color:#fff;
  }

  @import "paragraph";
}

// paragraph.scss
p{
   section.black &{
     color:#fff;
   }

   section.white &{
     color:#000;
   }
}
```

And the generated outout looks like this:

```
section.white html body div#wrapper section p {
  color: #000;
}
```

And I expect an output like this:

```
html body div#wrapper section.white p {
  color: #000;
}
```

Is that possible or is my interpretation completely wrong?

Comment: You are severely over-qualifying your selectors.  When will your div ever appear outside of an html or body element?  Your rules already specify paragraph colors when they appear within a section with a specific class, why do you need to nest them within the rules for sections?

Answer (score 0):

The parent selector isn't a reference to the next level up, but the *entire* composed selector after all imports/extends/mixin calls are resolved.

```
.one {
    .two {
        .three & {
            color: red;
        }
    }
}
```

The output will be this:

```
.three .one .two {
  color: red;
}
```

In this example, `&` is equal to `.one .two`, not `.two`.  It doesn't matter what method you use to nest your rules (extending, importing, or using mixins), the result is still the same.